# How to Lift the Limit on Maximum number of internal Redirects?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, recursion

Sometimes, not often, I see these lines in the error log:

```
[Sun Feb 20 11:53:38 2011] [error] [client 89.123.45.38]
 mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. 
 Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase
 the limit if neccessary.

[Sun Feb 20 11:53:38 2011] [error] [client 89.123.45.38] 
 Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable 
 configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if
 necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

**MEANING?** 
First of all, what does it mean? Does it mean that some users will see a broken page just because the limit of x redirects per page visit has reached?

**SOLUTION?**
I have mod rewrite to set up various beautifications of otherwise ugly /page.php?ln=de that are now /de/page  etc... within those pages something like 20 PHP-generated images are also rewritten to nicer image urls. Does this mean I have to set the limit higher than the 10 mentioned here? Is that 10 per second or 10 per visit or?

How can I change it in htaccess?
Any hint to this error is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That usually means you have an error in your rewrites causing an infinite loop.  The limit catches it from becoming infinite as a rule.

When it says:

> "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable 
>    configuration error."

That means in one request it has been rewritten 10 times.  That is a lot, and unless you have very complex rewrite rules going on, you most likely have a loop occurring.